# CSS transition not working for my filter: brightness()?

Tags: html, css

I have these icons that are images that I want to apply a filter on on-hover. However, it doesn't seem to be working.

My code:

```
.icon {
   -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
   transition:  all 1s ease;
}
.icon:hover {
   -webkit-filter: brightness(130%);
    filter: brightness(130%);
}
```

Comment: where is the html code?

Comment: it works, or you need to hover the icon, or its container http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGEZmM mind the selector you are using

Answer (score 8):

It should be noted that `filter` does not work on Internet Explorer or Firefox 35 or earlier. If you are using those browsers, it will not work. However, if you are using a compatible browser, as you can see here, it will work.

```css
img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(130%);
  filter: brightness(130%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cr2014studyabroad.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/pineapple-2.png" width=200 height=200 />
```

For more information on this experimental technology, visit these links

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you already have a `filter` property in your `.icon` selector?

I found that if that's the case and you didn't copy all of its values to your `:hover` selector, it will prohibit the use of most transition effects.

#### For example:

```css
.icon {
    filter: saturate(50%);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
    .icon:hover {
        filter: brightness(130%); /* doesn't work */
    }
```

#### vs

```css
.icon:hover {
    filter: saturate(50%) brightness(130%); /* does work */
}
```

---

#### Note

There seems to be an exeption for the first value of `filter`, but I would probably stick to the above example just to be sure.

```css
.icon {
    filter: brightness(130%) saturate(50%);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
    .icon:hover {
        filter: brightness(130%); /* does work */
    }
```